# Make Visual Studio warn missing await operator

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, .net-core, async-await

I ran in an error in production because one async method was being called from a sync method. That created a strange behaviour in the application. Finally, I figured it out but I'm worried about some new async methods being called like that in the code.

I want to know if there's a way to warn when I call an async method

```
public async Task TheMethodAsync()
{
   await Task.FromResult(0);
}
```

inside a sync method

```
public void OtherMethod()
{
    TheMethodAsync(); // <-- Warn this
}
```

BTW: We have too many methods to check manually.

Comment: There's [warning CS4014](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/compiler-messages/cs4014), but it only shows up in `async` methods.

Comment: In Visual Studio 2019 (16.7.2) with default settings that situation generates a CS4014 warning for me.

Comment: A warning for this has been around for a very long time, at least VS2013.  Be sure to not ignore warnings in the Error List window.

Answer (score 3):

By default you would be getting a *warning*. Unfortunately there is a whole gamut of ways to disable a *warning*, including resharper options

[image]

Check your build setting and various project and resharper options to make sure someone with *dirty little fingers* hasn't suppressed the `CS4014` *warming*, also check for any pragmas disabling warnings.

Now, if you really want to drive this home to your fellow developers, you can use `WarningsAsErrors` in your project file

Eg

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp3.1</TargetFramework>
    <Nullable>enable</Nullable>
    <WarningsAsErrors>CS4014</WarningsAsErrors>
  </PropertyGroup>
```

This will essentially create a *compiler error* on the `CS4014` *warning*, in turn making the build fail.

<sub>***Note** : Depending on how the *warning* was suppressed there is a good chance the above will have no effect, you need to find out why you are not getting the *warnings* in the first place*</sub>.

However, if all is working accordingly, you will then need to take *drastic action* to remove the compiler warning explicitly, forcing *junior devs* to revaluate *their place in life* before letting `async` methods run *unobserved*.

```
public static async Task Bob()
{
    await Task.Delay(1);
}

public static void Main(string[] args)
{
#pragma warning disable 4014
    Bob();
#pragma warning restore 4014
}
```

Or as mentioned in a worthy comment by [kapsiR](https://stackoverflow.com/users/574379/kapsir)

> You could even use a trick to get rid of the warning starting with C#
> 7 using Discards: `_ = Bob();`

Though in all honesty, if you have problems with people running *fire and forget* tasks, this is likely to exacerbate the problem.

Comment: Just additionally to your answer: You could even use a trick to get rid of the warning starting with C# 7 using Discards: `_ = Bob();`

Answer (score -2):

Change code to

```
public void OtherMethod()
        {
            Task.Run( async  () =>  await TheMethodAsync()  );
        }

    }
```